# Solving for outlier range, how to calculate on two different rows from same output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query below as:

```
SELECT
    age_quartile,
    MAX(age) AS quartile_break
    from 

    (SELECT
        full_name,
        age,
        NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY age) AS age_quartile
    FROM friends) AS quartiles
WHERE age_quartile IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY age_quartile)
```

This gives me output that looks like:

```
age_quartile | quantile_break
    1                 31
    3                 35
```

Desired Output:

```
outlier range 
25 
41
```

**where 25 = 31-6 and 41 = 35 + 6**

How can I add to my query above where I can my final desired output? My query currently gives me what the numbers are where I need to do one additional step to solve for the outlier range. thanks!

table data looks like:

```
friends

full_name        | age
Ameila Lara        1
Evangeline Griffin 21
Kiara Atkinson     31
Isobel Nieslen     31
Genevuve Miles     32
Jane Jenkins       99
Marie Acevedo      null
```

Comment: Please provide some set of data.

Comment: Yep, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: added how the data looks like in the original table, not sure why my question was voted to be closed?

Comment: I added how my data looks, and specifics on my current output based on my query and what i want to as my desired output

Comment: What is 6, how it should be computed?

Comment: sorry what the -6 and +6 represent is the outlier range < 25 and > 41 are outlier

Answer (score 0):

Dont now ntile is the right function to use here. But one way is to define the age quartiles in a temp table and join with age table and find the results. Just a try. There may be better way. Interested to see other answers.

Sample Query:

```
with friends as 
(
  select 'user1' as full_name, 31 as age union all
  select 'user2' as full_name, 55 as age union all
  select 'user3' as full_name, 75 as age 
),
quartiles_age as 
(
  select 1 as quartile, 0 as st_range, 25 as end_range union all
  select 2 as quartile, 26 as st_range, 50 as end_range union all
  select 3 as quartile, 51 as st_range, 75 as end_range union all
  select 4 as quartile, 76 as st_range, 100 as end_range 
)


SELECT
  fr.full_name,
  fr.age,
  qrtl_age.quartile,
  qrtl_age.end_range - fr.age as diff_age
FROM 
  friends fr
  join quartiles_age qrtl_age on fr.age between qrtl_age.st_range and qrtl_age.end_range
```

Fiddle URL : (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c48d209264e90d276cea6ae03f2a7af6)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the range using:

```
MAX(age) - MIN(age) AS age_range
```

That answers the *question* you asked.  Your sample data has an arbitrary `6` for the calculation, which the question does not explain.

Comment: Thanks, sorry the - represents the calculation for the outlier range, so < 25 and > 41 are considered outliers